# issue using with while loop, I want to show two buttons but only one appears

Tags: php

I have two records on my pdfs table.

And I want to show two buttons with a pdf link while I have records on my pdfs table, that corresponds to my two records.

The problem is that I have two records on my table but Im getting only one button, do you see why this can be happening?

If I do `echo read->rowCount();` I get "2", but Im getting only one button...

```
<?php
    $read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pdfs");
    $read->execute();
    $result  = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
       echo '<a href="'.BASE.'/uploads/pdfs/'.$result['pdf'].'" class="pdf">';
          echo '<button class="btn">';
             echo '<img  src="../images/pdf-icon.png" width="40" height="40"/>';
             echo '<span>'.$result['title'].'</span>';
          echo '</button>';
         echo '</a>';
         echo read->rowCount();
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result  = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

You are fetching twice, the first `$result` will be discarded without being used - and so you miss one button. Just remove the first line and it should work fine

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly! Them problem was really that, dont know how I didnt see it.